# A demi-continuous mapping which is not continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Let $(E,\left \| . \right \|)$ be a Banach space and $F: E\rightarrow E$ an operator.
>
> $F$ is said to be **demi-continuous** in $x$, if for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $E$ that converge strongly to $x$, the sequence $(T(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $T(x)$.

It's obvious that a continuous function is demi-continuous. I look for an example of a demi-continuous function which is not continuous.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Example) helps.

Comment: [Crossposted on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365917/82537)